# Iterate over Nested Hashmap ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY )

Tags: java, nested, hashmap

I want to iterate through the each field in "client" to assert that "message" and "code" is present and corresponds to the correct value in each object (first name, last name, city)

Class:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ErrorWithClient implements Iterable {

    @JsonProperty("client")
    Map<String, List<ErrorDescription>> errorDescription = new Map<String, List<ErrorDescription>>() {

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ErrorDescription> get(Object key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ErrorDescription> put(String key, List<ErrorDescription> value) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ErrorDescription> remove(Object key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends List<ErrorDescription>> m) {

        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> keySet() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<List<ErrorDescription>> values() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Entry<String, List<ErrorDescription>>> entrySet() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ErrorDescription:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ErrorDescription {

    @JsonProperty("message")
    String message;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    String code;

}
```

Response is achieved by API request to the server which consists of an empty "client": {}
Response:

```json
{
    "client": {
        "first_name": [
            {
                "message": "This field is required.",
                "code": "required"
            }
        ],
        "last_name": [
            {
                "message": "This field is required.",
                "code": "required"
            }
        ],
        "city": [
            {
                "message": "This field is required.",
                "code": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Recasting and for loop methods:

```java
try {
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    ErrorWithClient error = (ErrorWithClient) errorResp;
    try {
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(error);
        Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new Gson().fromJson(
                json, 
                new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>() {}.getType()
            );
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> client : map.entrySet()) {
            String firstName = client.getKey();
            System.out.println(firstName);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> field : client.getValue().entrySet()) {
                String code = field.getKey();
                String message = field.getValue();
                System.out.println(code + " " + message);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I tried different methods of recasting and mapping the json + for looping through it
So far described method is the closest i've got but I'm stuck with:

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 36 path $

What could be the solution is to describe response as class with getters and setters (but i doubt thats the issue)

Comment: Why is `errorDescription` an anonymous and _broken_ implementation of a map? You cannot store anything in this map, it will always be empty and you cannot retrieve anything from it. Just leave the property unassigned or assign an empty `new HashMap<>()`. The error you have posted usually indicates a problem with input JSON (invalid JSON), e.g. using an array as key (only strings can be keys)

Comment: @knittl if I use `HashMap<String, List<ErrorDescription>> errorDescription = new HashMap<>();` then error is pretty much the same expect column is 33 now

Comment: @knittl the json generated here `String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(error);` is actually correct, maybe the issue is here `Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>() {}.getType());`

Comment: The TypeToken does not match your class' structure. It maps to a `Map<String, List<ErrorDescription>`, not a `Map<String, Map<String, String>`. The anonymous map is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my needs in a different approach + taking into account @knittl comment

```
`try {
            JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
            ErrorWithClient error = (ErrorWithClient) errorResp;
            try {
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(error);
                JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
                JsonObject client = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("client");
                Map<String, JsonElement> map = client.asMap();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }`
```